# How to optimize PostgreSQL Row Security Policies that involve related tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, row-level-security

How do I optimize PosgreSQL Row Security Policies that involve related tables?  I'd like to have a policy on say the `Album` table restricting access by `ArtistId`.  But then, I'd also like to restrict access on the related `Track` table also by `ArtistId`, except that naturally the `Track` table doesn't have `ArtistId` though it does have a foreign key `AlbumId`.  I tried putting the Policy on `Album` to restrict by `ArtistId`, and then putting a Policy on `Track` to restrict just to related `Album` records, hoping that both policies would compose and effectively I would get just the `Track` rows for a given `ArtistId`.

That works, but the performance is poorer than I expected.  Maybe there's a better or more canonical way to write the policies, but I right now I can't think of any other way than I've done it.

Let me explain exactly what I'm doing:

I'm using the [Chinook](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database) database which has tables `Artist`, `Album`, and `Track`:

```sql
                   Unlogged table "public.Artist"
  Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 ArtistId | integer                |           | not null | 
 Name     | character varying(120) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "PK_Artist" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("ArtistId")
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""Album"" CONSTRAINT "FK_AlbumArtistId" FOREIGN KEY ("ArtistId") REFERENCES "Artist"("ArtistId")

                   Unlogged table "public.Album"
  Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 AlbumId  | integer                |           | not null | 
 Title    | character varying(160) |           | not null | 
 ArtistId | integer                |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "PK_Album" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("AlbumId")
    "IFK_AlbumArtistId" btree ("ArtistId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_AlbumArtistId" FOREIGN KEY ("ArtistId") REFERENCES "Artist"("ArtistId")
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""Track"" CONSTRAINT "FK_TrackAlbumId" FOREIGN KEY ("AlbumId") REFERENCES "Album"("AlbumId")
Policies:
    POLICY "artist_rls_policy" FOR SELECT
      USING (("ArtistId" = (current_setting('rls.artistID'::text))::integer))

                     Unlogged table "public.Track"
    Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 TrackId      | integer                |           | not null | 
 Name         | character varying(200) |           | not null | 
 AlbumId      | integer                |           |          | 
 MediaTypeId  | integer                |           | not null | 
 GenreId      | integer                |           |          | 
 Composer     | character varying(220) |           |          | 
 Milliseconds | integer                |           | not null | 
 Bytes        | integer                |           |          | 
 UnitPrice    | numeric(10,2)          |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "PK_Track" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("TrackId")
    "IFK_TrackAlbumId" btree ("AlbumId")
    "IFK_TrackGenreId" btree ("GenreId")
    "IFK_TrackMediaTypeId" btree ("MediaTypeId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_TrackAlbumId" FOREIGN KEY ("AlbumId") REFERENCES "Album"("AlbumId")
    "FK_TrackGenreId" FOREIGN KEY ("GenreId") REFERENCES "Genre"("GenreId")
    "FK_TrackMediaTypeId" FOREIGN KEY ("MediaTypeId") REFERENCES "MediaType"("MediaTypeId")
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""InvoiceLine"" CONSTRAINT "FK_InvoiceLineTrackId" FOREIGN KEY ("TrackId") REFERENCES "Track"("TrackId")
    TABLE ""PlaylistTrack"" CONSTRAINT "FK_PlaylistTrackTrackId" FOREIGN KEY ("TrackId") REFERENCES "Track"("TrackId")
Policies:
    POLICY "album_rls_policy" FOR SELECT
      USING ((EXISTS ( SELECT 1
   FROM "Album"
  WHERE ("Track"."AlbumId" = "Album"."AlbumId"))))
```

Tracks belong to Albums, and Albums belong to Artists.  As you can see, there also are Row Access Policies on `Album` and `Track`:

```sql
create policy artist_rls_policy ON "Album" for select to public using ("ArtistId"=(current_setting('rls.artistID'))::integer);

create policy album_rls_policy on "Track" for select to public
using (
  exists (
    select 1 from "Album" where "Track"."AlbumId" = "Album"."AlbumId"
  )
);
```

- `Album` has a policy to restrict access to `current_setting('rls.artistID')`
- `Track` has a policy to restrict access to related `Album` rows

The objective in the `Track` policy is to restrict access by `artistID` without having to repeat the policy that's already on `Artist`.  Put another way, the object is to be able to "compose" policies, in a way.

The trouble is that, while this works, the performance is poor.  In my experiments, relying on policies produces a query plan that does a sequential scan on `Track` with a sub-plan on `Album`, rather than doing join.

I *think* the problem stems from the `exists` check in the `Track` policy.  Maybe this is not the best way to write this policy.  But then, I can't think of any other way to write the policy.

I have all of this in a project in a GitHub repo here:

https://github.com/dventimihasura/hasura-projects/tree/master/rls-optimization-1

If you like, you can try it with:

```bash
docker compose up
```

And the connect to the database with

```bash
psql "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5433/postgres"
```

And then issue a simple query example:

```sql
set role "User";

set rls.artistID = '116';

explain analyze select * from "Track";

explain analyze select * from "Track" natural join "Album";

reset role;
```

The two queries yield the same results, but the second with the explicit join is about 10 times faster and has a different plan.